# How to bind item selected data to a button command in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, button, inotifypropertychanged, syncfusion, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a command button inside a syncfusion list view , I fired the command on the view model , but I dont know how to pass the data of the item selected . This is what I have

```
 <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="listView"  
                   SelectionBackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableData}"  ItemSpacing="10" >
                     <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <Label text="{Binding id requests}"/>
                           <Button Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference RequestsPage}, Path=BindingContext.CancelCommand}" ></Button>
                       </DataTemplate>
                       </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>                        
  </syncfusion:SfListView>
```

> View Model

```
         public ICommand CancelCommand
         {
           get;
           set;
         }
         CancelCommand = new Command(CancelBooking);

         void CancelBooking()
         {
          I need to capture the item source this button is inside each item that is 
          displayed in the list , I need to capture the data from this selection
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below links,

[binding-command-of-button-inside-the-itemtemplate-of-xamarinforms-listview-to-viewmodel-command](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/listview/mvvm#binding-command-of-button-inside-the-itemtemplate-of-xamarinforms-listview-to-viewmodel-command)

[how-to-delete-an-item-when-tapping-delete-button-in-listview-itemtemplate-in-mvvm](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10173/how-to-delete-an-item-when-tapping-delete-button-in-listview-itemtemplate-in-mvvm)